# Comparison Webdriver I/O & WD.js

Tags: react-native, appium, e2e-testing, webdriver-io

I need to create e2e test suite on react native project and after some reseach and tests with different solutions, I have choose Appium with Jest to made them.
Now I have to chose betwean [Webdriver I/O](https://webdriver.io/) & [WD.js](http://admc.io/wd/). I search a comparison betwean them online but I don't find anything.

Can you share yours exprerience with them and tell me what is the best and why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between webdriverjs and webdriverio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27174083/difference-between-webdriverjs-and-webdriverio)

Comment: WD.js -> https://github.com/admc/wd is not the as webdriverjs -> http://www.webdriverjs.com/

Comment: Oh sorry. My mistake! Would you mind including that link in your question for people like me?

Comment: The answer to the linked question also lists seven implementations to compare.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Slant comparison here [https://www.slant.co/versus/9647/9649/~webdriverio_vs_wd-js](https://www.slant.co/versus/9647/9649/%7Ewebdriverio_vs_wd-js)

Which in summary favours WebdriverIO significantly due to simpler syntax, (apparently) broader support for build and testing tools, better documentation, and is used by more/bigger companies.

WD's main pro, is just it's a bit better/simpler than webdriverjs.

The biggest con for WebdriverIO on that review that worried me was: "*Must run with WDIO to debug. Tasks written in this beautiful Selenium API can only be debugged using the provided WDIO task runner. You can't set breakpoints within tasks, but you can have WDIO pause the run between Selenium commands.*"
However, this doesn't seem to be true - I set up Mocha in my IDE as usual and could run and debug single test cases as normal.

Personally I have found more support, documentation and tutorials which use WebdriverIO e.g. in tools like Appium which I am using for React Native. Also "wd" is just a really difficult term to search for!

I failed to use "wd" in a Typescript project because there are no type definitions. I switched to JS, but it's rare to have to do that these days.

If you can get either of them up and running in your project (i.e. prove the tools integration), then the main deciding aspect would be the syntax. In this case I went for WebdriverIO beause I've personally always found the Selenium (Java-esque?) syntax to be weirdly verbose, clunky or even backwards.